# Selecting features within polygon from another layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, select-by-location, point-in-polygon

I'm using QGIS 1.8 with a PostGIS database and I have three PostGIS layers in QGISL: a lines, a points, and a polygon.

I'm trying to select features in the polygon layer and mark all points within this polygon.

For me the only way to do this is to use the button "Select by Polygon" but in this way, I cannot use an existing polygon for selection.

Comment: I tried using select within but it doesn't give me a selection, do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 79):

Two possible solutions:

1. You can use the ["Select by Location"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location) from `Vector > Research tools > Select by Location` and tick the "Use selected features only" checkbox.
2. If you want to actually export the points which intersect your selected polygon to a new shapefile then ["Intersection"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#intersection) from `Vector > Geopressing tools > Intersection` and again tick the "Use only selected features" checkbox. The input layer will be your points layer, and the select layer will be your polygon layer.

Comment: Furthermore, am I correct in adding that for the Vector processing to work, the following two conditions need to be met:
[1.] The layers need to have the same CRS; and 
[2.] The layer needs to be selected in the 'Layers' panel.

Comment: I do not have "Use only selected features" checkbox, see https://www.dropbox.com/s/hw2d422gh6wmoxm/Screenshot%202017-04-18%2011.40.41.png?dl=0 ? I have 2 layers, selected, and an object selected in one of the layers.

Comment: Take care when the layers are too large - they must be loaded into QGIS as a whole, which may be slow. It may be better to use a PostGIS query (e. g. via the DB Manager) instead.

Comment: @JaakL I had the same problem, but as you can see in the response below, the default behavior is to use the selected features if any: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/257060/121285

Comment: The intersect tool works so-so in edge/boundary conditions, I would suggest trying the _Select Within_ plugin suggested below

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest using the [Select Within](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SelectWithin/) Plugin.

> Centroid within, point of surface within, pole of inaccessibility
> within, percentage within, and mostly within selection. Works best
> with lines and polygons, but should work with other geometries as
> well.

[image: window]

Comment: Yes!!! Tried this tool once & it nailed it. Select by centroid is the behavior I would expect from the default QGIS _Select by Location_ tool, which did not perform very well on edge and boundary conditions.