# How to select only polygons that overlap with another layer?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, layers, overlapping-features, create

I have two shapefile layers created from different thresholds from a predictive model (Pink=80; Yellow=95).

Is there a way to create a new layer of only those pink polygons that contain yellow polygons and effectively erase the pink polygons that do not contain yellow?

If I use Geoprocessing - Intersect I will end up with just a copy of the yellow layer.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61753

Answer (score 2):

In ArcGIS Desktop you can use [Select Layer By Location](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000072000000) to do this:

> Selects features in a layer based on a spatial relationship to
>   features in another layer.

The relationship to use is INTERSECT.

Before running this add your shapefiles to a map so that you have them as layers.

After you have made the selection you can right-click on the selected layer to export it as a shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

Use select by location from selection tab.
Selection mode: select that layer from which you need to select
Source layer: overlapping polygon
Spatial selection mode : are within (clementini) the source layer feature