# Select shapes in one layer that overlap with shapes from another layer?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, intersection

This question is a duplicate of this: [How to select only polygons that overlap with another layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89779/how-to-select-only-polygons-that-overlap-with-another-layer)

But in my question I want to know how to do this in QGIS not in ArcGIS.
I want to be able to select shapes in one layer if they intersect /overlap shapes in another layer.

Intersection does not work because it gives me these odd silver polygons:

[image]

Because both the shapefiles are not perfectly aligned, it gives those small odd shapes, I would like to instead select entire shapes and not intersect the layers.

Comment: Can you share the data? From what you're describing and from what I can see of the data above, the intersect operation is proceeding as one would expect.

Comment: yes exactly, that is why I do not want to intersect, I just want to select the shapes

Comment: Use `select by location` with "intersects" as the geometry predicate. This will select the intersecting polygons without cutting them.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I needed!

Comment: @csk could you write an answer up so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Select by location` tool from the Processing Toolbox. Use "intersects" as the geometry predicate. This will select the intersecting polygons without cutting them.

[image]

If you want to extract the intersecting polygons to a separate layer, you can either

- use the `select by location` tool to select the intersecting polygons, then right click on the layer > export > export selected features
- or use the `extract by location` tool to extract the intersecting polygons in one step