# Selecting features within polygon from another layer using R or Python?

Tags: python, r, pyqgis, query, select

For [Selecting features within polygon from another layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61753/how-to-select-features-within-a-polygon-from-another-layer) the solution was to:

> use the "Vector->Research tools->Select by Location"

However, I would like to know how to do the same thing with either an R or Python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R's Spatial classes have select/extract idioms driven by the "[" operator - for extraction by index, number, name, logical map, or spatial overlay.

I think this is close to what you mean.

```
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
## generate some random points
n <- 5e4
d <- data.frame(lon = runif(n, -180, 180), lat = runif(n, -90, 90), x = seq(n))
## points as Spatial DataFrame
pts <- d
coordinates(pts) <- ~lon+lat
proj4string(pts) <- CRS(proj4string(wrld_simpl))

## plot the points
plot(pts, pch = ".")

## use one polygon to mark overlaying points 
sel <- pts[subset(wrld_simpl, NAME == "Australia"), ]
points(sel, col = "yellow", pch = 16, cex = 0.3)
```

See ?over for more general cases.

Answer (score 2):

For a Python script, you could call tools such as **Select by location** from the Python console:

```
import processing

processing.runalg('qgis:selectbylocation', input_layer, intersect_layer, u'intersects', 0, output_layer)
```

---

To see what parameters are required, you can call `processing.alghelp("qgis:selectbylocation")`:

```
>>> processing.alghelp("qgis:selectbylocation")

ALGORITHM: Select by location
INPUT <ParameterVector>
INTERSECT <ParameterVector>
PREDICATE <ParameterGeometryPredicate>
METHOD <ParameterSelection>
OUTPUT <OutputVector>


METHOD(Modify current selection by)
    0 - creating new selection
    1 - adding to current selection
    2 - removing from current selection
```

There are plenty of other *selection* tools which you can see using:

```
processing.alglist("select")
```

This lists all available tools with "select" in the name. You can then use them by checking which parameters are needed.

Source: [QGIS 2.8 Documentation: Calling algorithms from the Python console](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html).

Hope this helps!