# Selecting polygons within another polygons

Tags: r, sf

I have the same city map (BH city) for two different shapefiles with different locations. The first one is the "shared management", this one have bigger polygons, as we can see

```
shared_management <- read_sf(dsn = 'TGC_POP_DENGUE_00_11_12_TAXA.shp')
plot(st_geometry(shared_management))
```

[image]

And I have the smallers ones ("sectors")

```
sectors <- read_sf(dsn = 'SETOR_CENSITARIO_2010.shp')
plot(st_geometry(sectors))
```

[image]

Then I need a list of polygons of "sectors" which is inside of each polygon of "shared_management".

I know the number of polygons of "sectors" inside of which polygon of "shared_management". This number is given by

```
geo.int <- st_intersection(sector, shared_management)
geo.agg <- aggregate( ID_CS_2010~ID_TGC, data = geo.int, FUN = length)
geo.agg1 <- aggregate( ID_CS_2010~IDENT_TERR, data = geo.int, FUN = length)
head(geo.agg1)
IDENT_TERR ID_CS_2010
1          B1        112
2          B2         98
3          B3         85
4          B4        123
5          B5        127
```

Any idea of how can I obtain which polygons of "sectors" are inside of each polygon of "shared_management"?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Check this post to see how it can be done in both R and python: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162948/selecting-features-within-polygon-from-another-layer-using-r-or-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function st_join in the package sf to add the field you want from 'shared management' to the polygons within them that belong to 'sectors'

The code will look something like

```
library(sf)

geo_join <- st_join(shared_management, sectors, left = FALSE, largest = TRUE)
```

Setting the argument 'largest' to true will deal with overlap by assigning the sector the value from the shared_management zone that it overlaps with the most.

Once you have done this, you can filter the sector polygons by the field that indicates which of the larger polygons it fell within.

Comment: This is not the most stable solution. Please take a look at  DE-9IM (Dimensionally-Extended 9 Intersection Model) behavior to understand how GEOS deals with overlay.intersect operations.

Comment: Thanks @JeffreyEvans, this is helpful, as I'd not thought about the math behind this. When you say that it's not the most stable, do you mean that it can produce differing results?