# Null values in polygon intersection results

Tags: qgis, intersection

I am using 2.8.3-Wien to analyse two polygon layers, one with many more polygons (layer A) than the second. (layer B)

I need to know which of the polygons in A overlap with each of the polygons in B, as a new layer, with every overlap as a new polygon.

I've tried using Intersect, but I get a great big table with only half the data in it. It has all the polygons, labelled with data from B, but the fields which should say which polygon from A has overlapped is all null.

I had managed to get Intersect working with layers with less polygons, so is this just a processing power problem, or is there some other tool within QGIS that I can use?

I've not been using QGIS for long, so it's entirely possible I'm missing something really basic but vital.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting features within polygon from another layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61753/selecting-features-within-polygon-from-another-layer-using-qgis)

Comment: Not a duplicate, as either I'm using Intersect incorrectly, or it isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I misunderstand it. I thought that you want select overlapping polygons (*select by location*), now I get it that you want create layer with overlaps (*intersect*).

Answer (score 3):

I have diagnosed the problem. Shared field names!

Once I had created unique field names across both layers, the intersect worked perfectly.