# Add an attribute to polygon layer based on if it intersects with another layer

Tags: qgis, intersect

I have a layer of buildings and want to give it each polygon an attribute of 1 or 0, based on if it intersects a flood extent. Basically, a flooded or not flooded attribute.

Comment: Read https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61753/selecting-features-within-polygon-from-another-layer-using-qgis to select your buildings layer with your flood polygons then when selected calculate your field to 1 https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So the steps for anyone else interested are as follows:
1. Use the "Vector->Research tools->Select by Location" and tick the "Use selected features only" checkbox.
2. Use the Field Calculator to update the attributes on these selected features.

Comment: If you wish to answer your own question, please do that using an answer rather than a comment.