# Delete points inside a polygon

Tags: qgis, vector-layer, delete

I am working under QGis 3.4.8 Madeira under Windows 10.

I have uploaded two layers on my project.

Layer A is a points layer. Layer B is a polygons layer.

Some points of layer A are located in the area covered by some polygons of the layer B. I want to delete these points.

My final aim is to have a layer with buffer instead of the "free-range" points with the polygons. However, I cannot delete the points overlapping with the polygons.

My question is then:
How to delete SOME points of a layer depending on their overlapping with another layer ?

Comment: You select them with the right query ... and you delete them ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution to this would be to conduct a select by location **Vector->Research tools->Select by Location** followed by a delete selected features (possible within the attribute table). This would remove the points that fall within the polygon. [select by location Stack entry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61753/selecting-features-within-polygon-from-another-layer-using-qgis)

Comment: Also within the attribute table you can remove features from the selection. Hold down the `ctrl` key to unselect a single feature while leaving the other features selected.